# Why is there no onComplete() rxjs operator?

Tags: rxjs

Why rxjs contains no `onComplete` operator, i.e., one that allows to do something when the source observable completes? The `finalize` operator works for both completion and error, while I need to only react to completion.

Yes, I know that I can use the `onComplete` callback of the `subscribe()` function, but this is something completely different. Sometimes you only want to do certain stuff on completion inside the rxjs pipeline, and not inside the `subscribe` call.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The `tap` operator accepts three arguments (value, error, completion)

```
ons$.pipe(
    tap(null, null, () => console.log("Done")),
).subscribe()
```

or alternatively an observer, so you can do this:

```
obs$.pipe(
    tap({ complete: () => console.log("Done") })
).subscribe()
```

See the operator docs for more: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap

---

I would recommend the observer syntax as this is the syntax that has been recommended by Ben Lesh in the past since it's more expressive.